# Proving induction on a recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

The sequence is defined by:

$ a_0 = 1 $

$ a_n = 1+ \min(2a_{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor}, 3a_{\lfloor{n/3}\rfloor}) $

I need to prove that for all $ n $, $ a_n \ge n $.

I tried proving by choosing $ n = 6k + i $, where k is a natural number, and $ 1 \le i \le 5 $. However, because of the floor function, I've run into trouble. Am I looking at this from the wrong angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to prove the stronger inequality $\boxed{a_n \ge n+1}$ for all $n$ by strong induction.

The base case is clear, so let us assume that $n \ge 1$ and $a_k \ge k+1$ for $k = 0, \ldots,  n-1$. Then
$$
 a_{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} = \begin{cases}
 a_{n/2} \ge \frac n 2 + 1 & \text{ if $n$ is even,} \\
 a_{(n-1)/2} \ge \frac{n+1}{2} & \text{ if $n$ is odd.} \\
\end{cases}
$$
So in any case we have $a_{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} \ge \frac{n+1}{2}$, and similarly one shows $a_{\lfloor{n/3}\rfloor} \ge \frac{n+1}{3}$. It follows that
$$
 a_n \ge 1 + \min(2 \cdot \frac{n+1}{2}, 3 \cdot \frac{n+1}{3}) = n+2 > n+1
$$
and that concludes the induction step.